# is possible upload more than 1 image in 1 request using valums-file-uploader

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, multifile-uploader

I used the [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and it provides an option to uploading more than 1 image in 1 `ajax` request by doing 2 following things.

```
parallelUploads // set the number of images in 1 request
uploadMultiple // and set true so it can upload all in 1
```

Now i want to use this [valums-file-uploader](http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/) and i can't find the option to upload more than 1 images in 1 `request`. So is this possible in this plugin.

i read its documentation but can't solve my problem yet

Comment: @DownVoter what is unclear in it?
i want to send 5 images in ajax request using the 2nd mention plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check the library docs and i think you cannot do that currently in your second mention library without any custom changes.
For that either you have to use the same that you mention in first i.e `dropzone.js` or you can use this [library](http://www.plupload.com/) it have many features and much easier and nice then dropzone.js.

Comment: Thanks for response i will check that soon :)